# Elasticsearch filter to match array value of analyzed index

Tags: elasticsearch

Mapping of the field that im trying to make filter for:

```
  "genres": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
```

Theres an entry with these values:

```
  "genres": [
    "Animation",
    "History"
  ],
```

I am trying to make a filter, where i would input "Animation" - it would return me all entries that have animation as their genre.

Tried using **terms**:

```
GET /test/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": {
       "terms": {
         "genres": [
             "Animation",
             "History"
           ]

         }
       }
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

This resulted with no entries, as i read more i see that i need to remap my database and put "index": "not_analyzed" - then it would return some entries.

However, i can get these results by not using filter, using something like this:

```
GET /tmdb/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match": {
            "genres": "history"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "genres": "animation"
          }
        }          
      ]

   }
 } 
}
```

This does give me some results, but it only returns values that have both "animation" AND "history" as their genre.

So my question - do i need to remap my database, and add the "index": "not_analyzed" to the columns that i will use the filter for, or do i go with the second option (not using filters).

Edit:
Thought something like this would work, but its not working as i expected (the operator and does not seem to work for me):

```
GET /test/_search
{
 "query": {

   "match": {
     "genres": {
       "query": "animation", 
       "query": "history", 
       "operator": "and"
     }

   }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is almost correct. If you query the `genres` field (i.e. analyzed) you should use a `match` query instead

```
POST /test/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "should": [{
       "match": {
         "genres": "Animation"
         }
       }
     },{
       "match": {
         "genres": "History"
         }
       }
     }]
   }
 } 
}
```

If you query the `genres.keyword` field (i.e. not analyzed) then you can use the `terms` query

```
POST /test/_search
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "filter": {
       "terms": {
         "genres.keyword": [
             "Animation",
             "History"
           ]

         }
       }
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

Note: `not_analyzed` was used in ES 2.x and earlier, starting with ES 5 the using the `keyword` type is equivalent.

Comment: I was getting frustrated not finding the answer, this solves my problem. Thanks!